# chaincode event in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hi I am triggering chaincode event in application at the time of invoking is working fine for me and I have 2 organizations If I am invoking from org1 the event should be raised in org2(no invokation from org2) is there any possibility to trigger event like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have 2 (or more) orgs each with the chaincode installed/instantiated, and an endorsement policy that requires only one of the two (or more) orgs to endorse (sign) the transaction proposal. If you never send the proposal to the other org, you won't get an event from the chaincode (your app) because it won't be executed. Rather, when the orderer broadcasts the block with your transaction, each peer receiving it will simply validate the transaction and apply the read-write set to the ledger.

If you want an event from org1 and org2 then you will need to send the transaction proposal to peers of both orgs.